# how to get a value of multidimensional array on php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

hi im bulding a site with php that use a json api and i need to echo the values of an multidimensional array

```
 "troopsLevels": [
{
  "value": 5,
  "globalID": 4000000
},
{
  "value": 5,
  "globalID": 4000001
},
{
  "value": 4,
  "globalID": 4000002
},
```

this is a example of my json file what i need is to show the value "value" knowing depending of the globalID

but not sure how to do it

i was thinking something like

```
      $troop_lvl = $data['troopsLevels'];

if($troop_lvl['globalID'] == 4000000){echo $troop_lvl['value']}
```

but of curse this will not work as i dont specify the item [0]..[2]

but that actually thats what i need to avoid using [0] to select specific array i need to read all and only show the ['value'] when i give the globalid

i really hope yo can understand me english is not my mother language 
thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($troop_lvl as $key=>$value) {
  if($value['globalID'] == 4000000) {
    echo $value['value'];
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys soory i cant give you both the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach

```
foreach ($troop_lvl as $key=>$value) {
  if($value['globalID'] == 4000000) {
    echo $troop_lvl['value'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See below:

```
<?php
    $arr = array("test" => array("value" => 1, "value2" => 2), "test2" => array("value" => 21, "value2" => 22));
    $encode_arr = json_encode($arr);
    $decode_arr = json_decode($encode_arr);
    //print_r($decode_arr);
    foreach ($decode_arr as $key => $value) {
         if($value->value2==2)
            echo $value->value;
    }
?>
```

The output will be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you,

```
  $a = '{"troopsLevels": [
            {
               "value": 5,
               "globalID": 4000000
            },
            {
                 "value": 5,
                 "globalID": 4000001
             },
             {
                 "value": 4,
                 "globalID": 4000002
             }
         ]}';

  $abc = json_decode($a);
    foreach ($abc->troopsLevels as $row) {
        if ($row->globalID == 4000000) {
            echo $row->value;// prints value as 5 for the current input.
        }
    }
```